# Java не сохраняет оъект ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть две сущности `FileInfo` и `Issue`.
В БД  в таблице file_info есть foreign key redmine_id , который связан с колонкой redmine_id в таблице Issue.
Когда я пытаюсь сохранить сущность Issue  , в которую я добавляю FileInfo  , то в базе данных поле FileInfo остается пустым.
Что я делаю не так ?

```
Issue:
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Issue")
public class Issue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String fio;
    @Column
    private String phone;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String subject;
    @Column
    private Integer orgId;
    @Column
    private String orgName;
    @Column
    private String project;
    @Column
    private Long applicantId;
    @Column
    private String createDate;
    @Column
    private String updatedOn;
    @Column
    private String status;
    @Column
    private Integer redmineId;

  @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "issue",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
List<FileInfo> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
```

FileInfo:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "file_generator", sequenceName = "article_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

private String uuid;

private String name;

private String mimeType;

private LocalDateTime createDate;

private String path;

private Long size;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "redmine_id")
private Issue issue;
```

сервис:

```
     Issue issue = new Issue();
                List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new ArrayList<>();
                FileInfo fileInfo = fileInfoService.saveFile(file, filename, type);
    
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy,HH:mm");
    
                issue.setApplicantId(dto.getApplicantId());
                issue.setCreateDate(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
                issue.setFio(dto.getFio());
                issue.setPhone(dto.getPhone());
                issue.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
                issue.setDescription(dto.getDescription());
                issue.setSubject(dto.getSubject());
                issue.setOrgId(dto.getOrgId());
                issue.setOrgName(dto.getOrgName());
                issue.setRedmineId(dto.getRedmineId());
                issue.setStatus("Новая");
                issue.setProject("ПГУ");
                fileInfo.setIssue(issue);
                fileInfos.add(fileInfo);
                issue.setAttachments(fileInfos);
      

  issueRepository.save(issue);
```

в итоге получаю :

```
Подробности: Key (redmine_id)=(13908) is not present in table "issue".
```

Хотя такого redmine_id я не передаю , он пытается сослаться на обычный id .
как это решить ?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, если в `@Column` явно не передать имя колонки, то `Hibernate` решит, что `имя колонки= имя переменной`, поэтому вам стоит явно указать

```
@Column(name="redmine_id")
private Integer redmineId;
```